# Google do not index my posts

Tags: web, seo, google-search

I'd like to know why google do not index my posts on my blog writes in NodeJS.

Link of a post : http://icecom.fr/articles-icecom/9

Anthony

Comment: You've hardly given any information and this question won't be helpful to other people with similar problems in its current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why Google isn't indexing your website.

1. There are no links to your website. Google follows links on the internet to other pages. If there are no links to your website it won't find it.
2. You are denying access to Google through the robots meta-tag or robots.txt.
3. You haven't waited long enough yet, Google may take some time before it has indexed your website.

Of course you can supply Google with the proper URL's with a [sitemap]{https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en}. A good place to create this if you're new to it could be [here]{http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/}

@szenbalu already mentioned you can upload this sitemap.xml to Google Webmaster Tools and this way Google can index your site without the need of links. It is also faster most of the time.

Another way to get your website indexed through Google Webmaster Tools is the 'Fetch as Google' tool. In here you can tell Google to fetch and index your website. This is especially useful if you change content and want it reindexed.

About your specific case:
* You do not block Google with the meta robots tag
* I can not find a robots.txt file
* I can not find any links to your articles from [OpenSiteExplorer]{http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/}

I think that uploading a sitemap to Google Websmaster Tools + Using the Fetch as Google tool will get your site indexed within no time.

If you have any questions left, feel free to ask. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the robots.txt file and webmaster tools account joined to your page?
With webmaster tools you can upload sitemap that google will use to index pages.

Comment: I added webmaster tools to my last version of my website. Now, the pages names are not like the old version... And I do not know how to delete completely a website on webmaster tools et add back him...

Comment: You can delete the page from webmaster tools on the admin panel. Manage site -> Delete site
You can generate a sitemap with http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ and upload it on webmaster tools admin panel.